# Проблема с подключением Easy_maps (google maps api)

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api

Пытался подключить Easy Maps (https://pypi.org/project/django-easy-maps/) к сайту. Выполнил всё по инструкции, но карта просто не отображается на страничке. В консоле, из которой запускаю сервер, нет никаких ошибок.

Что я делал:

1) Установил Easy maps

```
pip install django-easy-maps
```

2) Добавил приложение в список

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'easy_maps',
```

3) Выполнил миграции

```
./manage.py migrate
```

4) Получил Google Maps API и вставил его в настройки

```
EASY_MAPS_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ___0123456789'
```

5) В html файл вставил код

```
{% load easy_maps_tags %}

<!-- Default map with 300x400 dimensions -->
{% easy_map "Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32" 300 400 %}
```

6) Запустил `python manage.py runserver`

Нашел в интернете, что у некоторых работало только с подключенным файлом maps.html.
Поэтому пробовал добавлять maps.html из примера к API в свой проект и в пункте №5 писать:

```
{% load easy_maps_tags %}

 <!-- Default map with 300x400 dimensions -->
 {% easy_map "Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32" 300 400 using 'map.html' %}
```

Результат такой же.